# WPF binding converter depending on settings

Tags: c#, wpf, settings, valueconverter

So here is my problem. I have some data measured in a certain unit and I want to be able to edit it in a numeric up/down, depending on the user's preferred physical unit.

Here are some code extract:

```
    public class Layout : ANotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _width = 360;
        /// <summary>
        /// Layout width in layout unit (1/72 inch)
        /// </summary>
        public double Width
        {
            get { return this._width; }
            set { this.AssignAndNotifyPropertyChanged(ref this._width, value); }
        }

        private double _height = 360;
        /// <summary>
        /// Layout height in layout unit (1/72 inch)
        /// </summary>
        public double Height
        {
            get { return this._height; }
            set { this.AssignAndNotifyPropertyChanged(ref this._height, value); 
        }
}
```

In my settings I have an enum that defines the user preferred unit:

```
public enum PhysicalUnits
{
    Inch,
    Centimeter,
    Millimeter
}
```

For now I use a MultiValueConverter that acts like this:

```
   public class LayoutToUserConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            PhysicalUnits unit = (PhysicalUnits)values[0];
            double value = (double)values[1];

            return UnitHelper.LayoutTo(unit, value);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object v, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (v == null)
                return null;
            double value = (double)v;
            return new object[] { MySettings.Default.PreferredUnit, UnitHelper.ToLayout(MySettings.Default.PreferredUnit, value) };
        }
    }
```

And in my XAML:

```
            <mahapps:NumericUpDown local:SettingsGrid.Header="Width" Interval="0.1" StringFormat="F2">
                <mahapps:NumericUpDown.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CurrentLayoutToUser}">
                        <Binding Source="{x:Static local:MySettings.Default}" Path="PreferredUnit" />
                        <Binding Path="Model.Width" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </mahapps:NumericUpDown.Value>
            </mahapps:NumericUpDown>
```

The problem is that when I change my value in my settings the ConvertBack is called, and since the unit is changed everything is going crazy. My previous approach was to use a regular ValueConverter and invalidates it when the settings changed, but I couldn't find a pretty way to do it.

Hope you can help me on that.

Comment: Have you tried passing PreferredUnit as a parameter to regular ValueConverter so you would know the unit when doing the conversion ?

Comment: @PonasJustas I did, but then I lose the Binding to the PreferredUnit and my bindings don't update when the setting change.